# The infinite sum problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to calculate the following sum

$$1 + (4/7) + (9/7^{2}) + (16/7^{3}) + (25/7^{4}) + \ldots$$

I dont have prior experience to deal with kinds of problem.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{7^{n-1}} = \frac{49}{27}$.

Comment: @AlexSilva: I think you want $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{7^{n-1}} = \frac{49}{27}$$

Comment: Easiest way  to do this problem, is to treat it like a power series, and perform some kind of an integration..

Comment: More general: for $\mid a \mid > 1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^b}{a^{n-1}} = a\cdot Li_{-b}(a^{-1})$.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i m still confused to understand that how u stopped at 49/27 @AlexSilva

Comment: What exactly is Li?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez, the polylogarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${\frac {1}{1-x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$
differentiate  it
$${\frac {1}{(1-x)^2}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$
multiply by $x$
$${\frac {x}{(1-x)^2}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}$$
differentiate it
$$({\frac {x}{(1-x)^2}})'=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }n^2x^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }n^2x^{n-1}$$
at $x=\frac{1}{7}$
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{7}}{(1-\frac{1}{7})^3}=\frac{49}{27}$$

Comment: how to come to answer at49/27

Comment: @avkavk take the L.H.S and plug $x=\frac{1}{7}$

Answer (score 2):

You are facing the problem of computing$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2}{x^{n-1}} $$ Let us rewrite $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2}{x^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(n(n-1)+n)}{x^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(n-1)}{x^{n-1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nx^{n-1}}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2}{x^{n-1}}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(n-1)}{x^{n-2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nx^{n-1}}$$ The first sum is just the second derivative of a well known function and the second sum is its first derivative.

If it was $n^3$ instead of $n^2$, the trick would consist in writing $$n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+An(n-1)+Bn$$ and a simple manipulation will give $A,B$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: For $|x|<1$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$Differentiate to get: $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$ Differentiate once again to obtain $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k$: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k=\frac{x(1-x+x^2)}{(1-x)^3} $$ Here $|x|=1/7<1$, so we can use the above result.

Comment: ok i know this@AlexSilva

Comment: @Shrey, take a look at your derivatives!